# what are the system requirements for the full version of ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

and what hardware do you recommend running it on

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263089/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-the-full-version-of-ros/) by [Tzvi Yudin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30609/tzvi-yudin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS can run on anything from a Raspberry Pi to a high-end Intel Xeon server.

The message-passing layer in ROS has fairly minimal requirements and can run on pretty much anything that can run Linux, but many of the more complex mapping and motion-planning packages may require significantly more resources.

If you describe the application that you're trying to run or the type of robot that you're trying to create you'll probably get a better answer.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1